# PreBid AMP Header Bidding Implementation - Cross Origin Frame Issue

Tags: amp-html, prebid.js

I'm tryng to use [PreBid on AMP pages](http://prebid.org/dev-docs/show-prebid-ads-on-amp-pages.html), but I'm getting a cross-origin frame issue with my [remote.html](https://github.com/prebid/Prebid.js/blob/master/integrationExamples/gpt/amp/remote.html) file:

I hosted my remote.html file with Amazon S3 and updated the CORS configuration to allow my domain. but I'm still getting the following error in my browser.

```
Blocked a frame with origin "https://s3.amazonaws.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame. Error: Blocked a frame with origin "https://s3.amazonaws.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
at Zc (https://3p.ampproject.net/1504040004635/f.js:82:23)
at HTMLIFrameElement.<anonymous> 
(https://3p.ampproject.net/1504040004635/f.js:81:346)
```

My CORS Configuration file for my S3 bucket is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
<AllowedOrigin>https://3p.ampproject.net</AllowedOrigin>
<AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
<AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
<AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
<MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
<AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
<CORSRule>
<AllowedOrigin><http://my_domain_name.com></AllowedOrigin>
<AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
<AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
<AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
<MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
<AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
<CORSRule>
<AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
<AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Any idea on how I might resolve this issue?

thanks in advance.